# SQL Server Split And Table Insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, split, temp-tables

I want to do the following using SQL Server 2005.

1. Create a stored procedure that takes a `varchar()` comma "," delimited param
2. Split / Explode the `varchar()` param and insert the values in a temporary table

Something that will do the following:

```
INSERT INTO #temp_table SPLIT('john,peter,sally',',');

SELECT * FROM #temp_table;
```

Is there a function or stored procedure that will perform a split?

If so, how does it work?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split String in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server does not have a string split function out of the box, but you can create one like [this](http://www.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return       
end
```